# Get hosting provider for IP with Python

Tags: python, ip, hosting

I have a simple Python script that gets the IP for a domain and looks up the country using Maxmind. I would like that script to also get what webhosting company that hosts that IP/site. Is that possible, and if so how? I've searched this site and elsewhere without much luck.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr("69.59.196.211")
```

> ('stackoverflow.com', ['211.196.59.69.in-addr.arpa'],
>   ['69.59.196.211'])

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get the organisation name (AS number/name) behind the IP (not the DNS name):

```
>>> import pygeoip
>>> ai = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIPASNum.dat', pygeoip.MEMORY_CACHE)
>>> ip = '1.1.1.1'
>>> asn = ai.org_by_addr(ip)
>>> print asn
AS15169 Google Inc.
```

-- ab1

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with the latency of calling a 3rd party service you could use the http://ipinfo.io API (my service), which returns both geolocation and company information, eg:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io
{
  "ip": "67.188.232.131",
  "hostname": "c-67-188-232-131.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.4192,-122.0574",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",
  "postal": "94043"
}
```

Here's a simple python example that uses the excellent `requests` library:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/67.188.232.131/json')
>>> r.json['org']
u'AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.'
>>> r.json['city']
u'Mountain View'
```

For more details take a look at http://ipinfo.io/developers